# Edit XML files in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

Is there a simple/better way in Excel to EDIT XML files?
I got a XML file (see below). And I would like to edit directly some inner values and save it in the same format again.
Form Below I would like to change:
Username (MisterX)
User Role (Admin)
Values of the permissions for all the applications (YES/NO/Numeric value)
(adding now permissions aside from A,B,C is not needed just changing the value)

The XSD to the XML is available.
When I open the XML I got three options displayed by Excel:
1: As an XML Table -> Selecting this displays a Excel file and all Values are displayed in one row:

```
[MisterX][Admin][YES][NO][1.5][YES][YES][2.0][YES][12][NO]
```

This is stupid because I don't see that names of the permissions. Saving it from here as XML removes the link to the XSD and adds the "ns1:" as prefix.

2: As a read only Workbook -> Selecting this displays a Excel file and all Values are displayed in one row + a header for the row with the names of the values like:

```
[/username][/userrole][AppDesc/Applic1/PermissionA][AppDesc/Applic1/PermissionB] ...  
[MisterX][Admin][YES][NO] ...
```

This would be nice if it wouln't be in a row because this way I cant easily read the names of the values. Saving is not possible as XML (no mapping)

3: Use XML Source Task pane -> Shows an empty Excel + opened "XML Source" pane.
Here I could create a mapping between the XML fields and cells for saving.
But still I don't see the current values.

Is there a way to edit the Excel file in a more comfortable way in Excel?
(Microsoft Excel 365 Pro)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<desclist xmlns="http://www.example.com/ws/aimsl/desclist" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ws/desclist desclist.xsd">
        <username>MisterX</username>
        <userrole>Admin</userrole>
        <AppDesc>
            <Applic1>
                <PermissionA>YES</PermissionA>
                <PermissionB>NO</PermissionB>
                <PermissionC>1.5</PermissionC>
            </Applic1>
            <Applic2>
                <PermissionA>YES</PermissionA>
                <PermissionB>YES</PermissionB>
                <PermissionC>2.0</PermissionC>
            </Applic2>
            <Applic3>
                <PermissionA>YES</PermissionA>
                <PermissionB>12</PermissionB>
                <PermissionC>NO</PermissionC>
            </Applic3>
        </AppDesc>
    </desclist>
```

Comment: What is the complicated/worse way you are using now?  Also, you show five permissions for the applications, but each application only has three permissions.  Do you need to add permissions also?

Comment: [Overview of XML in Excel - Excel](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/overview-of-xml-in-excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: now, it is not working because it adds this "ns1:" prefix. the 5 permissions are option that I can fill there. no I don't need to add new permissions per application there are the permissions (ABC) defined and only the values are changed.

Comment: I'm sorry. But the problem with your current method is not clear to me. If the only problem you are having is adding an `ns1:` prefix, then you need to change something in your save routine.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: The Problem is 1: On opening I don't see what value is wath permission. 2: on saving the change of the structure.    it is excel ... how could I change the save routine?

Comment: @DavidPostill: this seems to be outdated or inaccurate ... or what should actually help form that page? e.g.: Developer tab is not available.

Comment: *how could I change the save routine?* How could I possibly answer that? You've not provided any information as to your current method of trying to alter the xml data and then save it.  All you've written is that you are wondering if there is a better way. You need to read in the raw xml data; access the nodes using a variety of techniques; change them; and then write them back.  But with what you've provided, it is not possible for me to tell where you might make changes in that process to do it "better" and avoid this "ns1" problem you mentioned.

Comment: By the way, if you are looking for someone to write an `Excel xml modifier` program for you, I think you're in the wrong place.

Comment: OK, I now see what you are doing.  See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

To edit your xml data manually, you can do the following

- On the Developer Ribbon, XML Tab, **Import**
- You may see this window:

[image]

- Click `OK` and import to `A1`
- On that same tab, click `Source` which will open the XML Source pane with the mappings
- As you select cells on the worksheet, the different nodes will be highlighted in the XML Source pane, so you can see what is being referred to.
- You can then alter the different values and save the document back as an XML document.  The changes will be maintained.
- With regard to the `ns1:`, I refer you to [Excel to XML Namespace Prefix Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463769/excel-to-xml-namespace-prefix-customization).  But there are other articles in SO that have can guide you in removing the `ns1:`, should you choose to do that.

[image]
 -